# ROS base - rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I install/start rviz, when I only have installed ROS base (Ubunto 10.04, electric)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32101/ros-base---rviz/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install the ROS visualization stack if you want to use RVIZ:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-visualization
```

You could basically also checkout RVIZ source and manually install all dependencies but i think you really should NOT do this...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem might be caused by Ogre or OpenGL. You can check:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

for Troubleshooting (especially section 3.4 might be of interest for you).

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1